# Im just trying to pass the input to my Js, what have I done wrong?

Tags: javascript, html

Here is the HTML

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd"> 
<html lang="en"> 
<head> <script src = "reverse cypher.js"> </script> 
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"> 
<title>Title Goes Here</title> </head>
 <body>  
  <body> 
 <h1>
    <p> Ceaser Cypher </p>
 </h1>
 
 <div>
    <form>  
    Message:<input type="text"/>
    </br>
    <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="cypher()" id = "messageInput"/>
    </br>
    Encode Message: <output = "text" id = "encode" />
    </form>
</div> 
 
 </body> 
 </html>
```

Here is the JS

```
     function cypher(messageInput){
    let inputMessage = document.getElementById("messageInput");   
    let encodedMess =[];                                      
    let upperAlphabit = new Array( 26 ).fill( 1 ).map( ( _, i ) => String.fromCharCode( 65 + i ) );    //upper and lower case alphabit
    let lowerAlphabit = new Array( 26 ).fill( 1 ).map( ( _, i ) => String.fromCharCode( 97 + i ) ); 
    let reverseLower = lowerAlphabit.reverse();
    let reverseUpper = upperAlphabit.reverse();
    
    
    
       for (let i = 0; i <= inputMessage.length; i++)
    
            for(let b = 0; b <= upperAlphabit.length; b++)                                          // cycles through the upper/lower case alphabit finding a match and 
                {
                    if(lowerAlphabit.charAt(b) == inputMessage.charAt(i))    
                        encodedMess.fill(reverseLower.charAt(b)); 
                    
                    if(upperrAlphabit.charAt(b) == inputMessage.charAt(i))    
                        encodedMess.fill(reverseUpper.charAt(b));    
    
                }
             
                encodedMess = document.getElementById("encode").innerHTML = " "+ encodedMess;
                        
    
                console.log(encodedMess);
    
    }
```

When I run this it returns an empty array. I don't understand. I am trying to pass the data from the input to the JS so I can run a cypher on it. What did I do wrong? As you can already tell I am new to this so and advice would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value is at inputMessage.value